# How do make Windows Form Usable?

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

When I start the application it loads the form, but when I mouse over it, the mouse cursor stays in the loading state. Not only that, the menu isn't showing either.
    // MyForm.cpp

```
MyForm::MyForm () 
{
    this->Size = System::Drawing::Size (300, 300);
    InitializeComponents ();
    this->Show ();
}


MyForm::~MyForm ()
{

}

void MyForm::InitializeComponents () 
{
    // Create componentes
    mainMenu = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MainMenu ();
    fileMenuItem = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MenuItem ();
    aboutMenuItem = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MenuItem ();

    // Intizlize components
    fileMenuItem->Text = "File";
    aboutMenuItem->Text = "About";

    // Bind main menu to this form
    this->Menu = mainMenu;
}

// Main
MyForm ^myForm = gcnew MyForm ();
Console::ReadKey ();
```

Comment: This is not C++, it's C++/CLI.  Tag changed.

Comment: It is not a console mode app.  Calling Application::Run() is **not** optional.

Comment: @ Han Passant What does that mean?

Comment: @HansPassant Okay, I used the Application class and it worked? I don't know why, can you explain?